# ios: Why is a temporary load of XIB, to get frame height, corrupting memory?

Tags: ios, memory-management, memory-corruption, loadnibnamed

I am using trying to get the heights for several UITableCellView's that are defined in their own XIB.  I create a list of the heights that are used in the callback heightForRowInPathIndex of the UITableViewDelegate.  When I do this, the application crashes as-if a memory corruption.

```
arrayOfTableCellView = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TableCellXyz" owner:self options:nil];

UITableViewCell *cellOfXyz = (UITableViewCell*) [arrayOfTableCellView objectAtIndex:0];

[arrayCellHeights insertObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:cellOfAlerts.frame.size.height] atIndex:kIndexXyz];

[arrayOfTableCellView release];
```

I have looked at the retainCount and it is as expected.

Comment: Just as a note: you shouldn't trust retainCount. You don't know what goes on behind the scenes. What kind of error do you get? I assumge it's EXC_BAD_ACCESS?

Comment: BTW - the error was jumping out of the application.  During my Instrumentation, my experience is that most of these turn out to be memory retain/release inconsistency.  In some cases, zombies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the answer is simple, from the docs:

> **Return Value**
>
> An array containing the top-level objects in the nib file. The array
> does not contain references to the File’s Owner or any proxy objects;
> it contains only those objects that were instantiated when the nib
> file was unarchived. You should retain either the returned array or
> the objects it contains manually to prevent the nib file objects from
> being released prematurely.

It seems like you are just assigning the return value to `arrayOfTableCellView`. If you want to retain the return value, and `arrayOfTableCellView` is actually a property on your viewController, then you should assign it using `self.arrayOfTableCellView`.

**If you are not retaining it, you don't have to release it because you do not own it.** So when you actually get the array like this

```
NSArray *arrayOfTableCellView = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TableCellXyz" owner:self options:nil];
```

then you don't want to have

```
[arrayOfTableCellView release];
```

in there, because you didn't allocate the object.

EDIT:

Just to calarify this to you, I just ran your code, with the expected result:

```
NSArray * arrayOfTableCellView = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"JLUViewController" owner:self options:nil];

UITableViewCell *cellOfXyz = (UITableViewCell*) [arrayOfTableCellView objectAtIndex:0];

[arrayCellHeights insertObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:cellOfAlerts.frame.size.height] atIndex:kIndexXyz];
```

The above code does not crash or cause a leak. Instruments does not report a leak, so you'd be fine.

If you add

```
[arrayOfTableCellView release];
```

though it will crash, reporting EXC_BAD_ACCESS, because you tried to release an object you didn't own. Notice how i made the NSArray a local variable? You should do the same because you don't need it to be a property, since you just use it inside the function's scope. Also please not that if `arrayCellHeights` is a property inside your viewcontroller, always use `self.arrayCellHeights` to access it.

Comment: OK - let me do some more testing.  But when I originally did not "retain", the Instruments declared a leak.  If I "NSLog" the array's retain count, it is set to 1, which I assume is from the loadNibNamed.  Having said that, your comment above in the question states that I cannot trust the value as it is a magic value, behind the scenes.

Comment: @mobibob: did this get you anywhere?

Comment: My crash was a side effect of a iOS4 problem with the application memory footprint.  Apparently iOS5 allocates more memory for the initial launch (x4 or x10) compared to iOS4.  As soon as I reduced my application initial size, the problem went away - for a little while.  It later crashed for the same reason, but runs forever on iOS5.  Try to convince management of that :)